# you are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v9.0

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I have the following error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v9.0. in /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:174
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Client.php(215): FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Response))
#1 /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Request.php(286): FacebookAds\Http\Client->sendRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#2 /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(165): FacebookAds\Http\Request->execute()
#3 /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Api.php(214): FacebookAds\Api->executeRequest(Object(FacebookAds\Http\Request))
#4 /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/ApiRequest.php(187): FacebookA in /var/www/html/newAdsM/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php on line 174
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's impossible to help you if you don't even ask a question. But... maybe the problem is what the error message says the problem is, and to fix it, you should do the thing that the error message tells you to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
The current latest version for Facebook Business SDK is v5.0.5
The current latest version for Graph verison 9.0

GoTo: 
<pre>vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/ApiConfig.php
class ApiConfig {
  const APIVersion = '9.0';
  const SDKVersion = '5.0.1';
  const TYPE_CHECKER_STRICT_MODE = false;
}
</pre>
Change like this
```